# can't activate flutterfire_cli on linux

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a Linux machine running ubuntu 21.10 where I installed flutter manually. and when I try to activate flutterfire_cli it shows this error[output from dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC82s.png)

this is the output from flutter doctor[flutter doctor output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE82V.png)

versions I'm using
flutter: 3.0.3 channel stable, Dart SDK version: 2.17.5, firebase: 11.1.0

Comment: Odd, you have installed Firebase tools  `npm install -g firebase-tools`?

Comment: Yes, i did install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this, I installed firebase using the auto-install script previously I used npm and run the "dart pub cache clean" command I don't know which fixed it but it works.